# error: WITH expected this input to be an agentset, but got a patch instead

Tags: netlogo

I've been trying since yesterday to code the following: I have a world with 1 turtle in each patch (sprout command). I would like the turtle to check the 8 neighbors from the patch it is in. I did it like this: let neighWithVeg count neighbors of patch-here with [veg-value > 0.2]. But the error appears: WITH expected this input to be an agentset, but got a patch instead

Can someone help me?

```
patches-own [
  veg-value
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
   ask patches [ 
    sprout 1 
  ]        
end


  to go
 ask turtles [
   neighboring
  ]
end

to neighboring
    let neighWithVeg count neighbors of patch-here of [veg-value > 0.2] ;; HERE THE ERROR
    ifelse neighWithVeg = 0
    [
      move
    ]

    [
      move-to one-of neighbors of patch-here with [veg-value > 0.2]
    ]  
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For future questions, please only show the relevant code - probably the procedure with the error and the procedure that calls it. Also, NetLogo tells you which line generated the error.

I am guessing this is the line generating the error:

```
let neighWithVeg count neighbors of patch-here with [veg-value > 0.2]
```

You don't actually need `of patch-here` because the code is taking the perspective of the relevant patch anyway. But if you did, then you need [ ] for `of`, so it would be `[neighbors] of patch-here`.

But I think what you want is:

```
let neighWithVeg count neighbors with [veg-value > 0.2]
```

Comment: Hi JenB, thanks for your help. And I'm going to pay attention and put only the part of the code that has the error. Thanks for the tip

Comment: JenB, I went to see and it didn't work. I would like to code the following: l have a world with 1 turtle in each patch (sprout command). I would like the turtle to check the 8 neighbors from the patch it is in. I did it like this: let neighWithVeg count neighbors of patch-here with [veg-value > 0.2]. But the error appears: WITH expected this input to be an agentset, but got a patch instead. When I use the of, it doesn't look at the patches next to the patch the turtle is on

Comment: I don't understand your comment. That is the code that my answer tells you how to fix. There is no `of` in the fix